# Homework proof of cubic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, continuity, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I was asked to prove that any cubic polynomial with real coefficients has at least one real root.
I am not very good at proving things but I made an attempt, It was a bit of a draft and not perfect also I didn't know how else to say that if the cubic term is larger than all the other terms combined then that value for x would hold regardless of the values for the other terms, so if someone could help me with this I'd really appreciate it, or if someone could help me improve it, tell me how I can fix some of my errors, or show me a more elegant way to prove it. Thanks! :)

Here are my proof's so far:
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you were to write the polynomial as $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)$ then you can create a quadratic out of two of the factors if, say $a_2$ and $a_3$ were in $\Bbb C$ but not all because you would have complex coefficients in the expansion. Hence one of them has to be a real root, and the complex ones conjugates of each other

Answer (score 1):

This comes directly as a consequence of the Intermediate Value Theorem, which states that if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$, and the function f is continuous on the closed interval [a,b], then $\forall{y_0}$ where $f(a)<y_0<f(b)$ ,$\exists{x_0}\in[a,b]$ with $f(x_0)=y_0$. So if you choose an extremely large negative value for $a$, an extremely large value for $b$ and set $y_0=0$, which follows $f(a)<0<f(b)$, $\exists{x_0}\in[a,b]$ with $f(x_0)=0$. Since $x_0\in[a,b]$, we can also say $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, completing the proof.

Comment: Almost correct. With the notation of the question, is $a<0$ it's the other way around. And when you write "extremelly small value", it's actually an extremely large negative value.

Comment: What do you mean by the other way around because $a<b$. Sorry if I've just made a silly mistake.

Comment: But you need to account for the coefficients signs if the coefficient of the cubic is negative an extremely negative value will give f(x) >0.
I was kinda of hoping to find out if my method for choosing a and b were correct or can it be improved.
Also I wonder if it would be sufficient to just show that as x --> infinity and x --> negative infinity that f(x) --> infinity and f(x) --> negative infinity depending on the sign of the coefficient, since it would show that there exists an x1 and x2 s.t. f(x1) > 0 and f(x2) < 0

Comment: @jacobbradley You don't need to choose. It would be possible (there are ways to find bounds for the roots), but it's useless, as you just need to know that the limit at $\infty$ is $+\infty$ on one side and $-\infty$ on the other. And if you divide by $a$ (the coefficient of highest degree), then it's $+\infty$ for $x\to+\infty$, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Yeah I ended up going for the limit argument and I already submitted. I wasn't sure if it was acceptable so I was a bit worried so thanks for reassuring me. However I didn't divide by a I just separated it into cases when a>0 and a<0.

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant way to prove this may be the following:

Since the polynomial has real coefficients, then, by the complex conjugate root theorem, if there is a non-real root, it's conjugate will be a root as well. Thus, there has to be an even number of non-real roots. Since the polynomial has 3 roots, there can be at most two non-real roots. It follows that there is at least one real root. 
Otherwise, there will be 3 real roots.

If you use the intermediate value theorem,

For $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$, assume $a>0$. This can be done without loss of generality, because if $a<0$, both sides can be multiplied by $-1$ to make the coefficient of $x^3$ positive.

Now, you can apply IVT: $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$.
Since $f$ is continuous everywhere, there is at least one root in the range $(-\infty,+\infty)$

Comment: My problem is that we haven't learnt this in class therefore I cannot use this theorem. :(